# jquery regex replace between 2 delimiters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to replace to do a string replace. I would like to replace everything that is between the last `/` and `.gif`.

I am playing with this snippet of code but can't get it to work (regex is not my strong point).

jQuery

```
var str = '/foo/folder1/folder2/123img.gif';
var newFileName = 'newImg';
var replaced = str.replace(/\/\d|a-z+-.gif/, newFileName );
$('p').text(replaced);
```

Output

```
/foo/folder1/folder2newImg23img.gif
```

Desired output

```
/foo/folder1/folder2/newImg.gif
```

By using `d` and `|` and `a-z` within my regex pattern, I was hoping it would remove digits and letters - but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hkhfk531/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\/]+(\.gif)$/i, newFileName + '$1')
//=> "/foo/folder1/folder2/newImg.gif"
```

`[^\/]+` matches 1 or more of any char that is not `/` before `.gif` which is captured in a capturing group.

Here is a lookahead based solution to avoid capturing group:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\/]+(?=\.gif$)/i, newFileName)
//=> "/foo/folder1/folder2/newImg.gif"
```